# What is the difference between int64 and int64_t in C++?

Tags: c++, int

I am new to c++ and coding in general. so this question might be noobish. what is the difference in using type int64 or int64_t. I saw that one of the software devs modified their source on github and all of the int64 to int64_t.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`int64_t` is a Standard C++ type for a signed integer of exactly 64 bits. `int64` is not a standard type.

The first C++ standard didn't have fixed-width types. Before `int64_t` was added to Standard C++, the different compilers all implemented a 64-bit type but they used their own names for it (e.g. `long long`, `__int64`, etc.)

A likely series of events is that this project originally would `typedef int64` to the 64-bit type for each compiler it was supported on.  But once compilers all started to support Standard C++ better, or once the person who wrote the code found out about `int64_t`, the code was switched over to use the standard name.

Comment: could you please elaborate, does that mean `int64` might have 32 bits on 32-bits platform? or another thing besides being not standard?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more. does that mean it will be removed from compilers sooner or later? this might be another noob question. but I don't much understanding of these yet

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: It's unlikely that anyone would define a 32-bit type and call it `int64`. The point is that, since `int64` is non-standard, it may not exist at all. `int64_t`, on the other hand, is defined by all conforming C compilers (as long as they support at least the 1999 version of the standard). Any code that uses `int64` (unless it defines it itself) is non-portable. Changing that code to use `int64_t` was a good idea.

Comment: thank you, Keith. I was hoping Matt would include something like this in the answer. =)

Comment: @user2185284 I have added some speculation :)

Comment: @KeithThompson Technically it might not exist - these types are optional; e.g. a compiler might offer 32-bit int and long, but 128-bit long long, and not offer any 64-bit type.  But it seems (at present anyway) unlikely that such an implementation would ever exist