# C++ gcc _builtin function gives unexpected answer

Tags: gcc, c++14, built-in

`Int64_t n=7;` after printing `__builtin_clz(n)` answer is `29` rather than the expected answer `61`.

Comment: What is `Int64_t`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582049/what-is-the-difference-between-int64-and-int64-t-in-c

Comment: That's `int64_t`. What is `Int64_t`?

Comment: Sorry it's just typing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the signature for the intrinsic you are using:

`int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`

As you can see it works on 32-bit unsigned. It treat your 64 bit integer as a 32 one. Since 7 has 4 bits set it return `32-3 = 29`

Try `__builtin_clzl;` or `__builtin_clzll` instead.

[details here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Answer (score 5):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html states:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`

I.e. `n` is implicitly converted to an `unsigned int` because that's what the function takes.

There's also `int __builtin_clzll (unsigned long long)` if you need more bits.